# How to remove required field validation in magento 1.7.0.1?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am beginner in magento.I need to remove required field for select option in configurable products and add into shopping cart pages in magento.In product details page,customers can purchased set of product and individual product.For example, Product A can buy shirt model and product B can buy pant model but product A and product B can show shirt and pant.so i am using  product

[image]

How to remove required field and add into shopping cart page in magento? Please advice me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong kind of products. Configurable product options are always required.

I think you need to look at using grouped or bundled products to do what you want.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-grouped-product

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product/producttype

Comment: Hi @Andrew......thank for responsive answer....How to solve it...please advice me... how it`s possible?

Comment: Look at these to see the features of particular product types to see which matches your exact needs:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-grouped-product

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product/producttype

Comment: Hi @Andrew..I need to remove required value for particular select option...is it possible..........ah? Please advice me...